Why is Maven trying to find SNAPSHOTS?
I'd like our projects to use the latest versions of SpringFramework-5.x available at build-time. To this end, I set the version-range as:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>[5,5.99]</version>
        </dependency>

This works perfectly fine on my desktop, but, when building through our private Gitlab-instance, I see the build cycling through the nonexistent SNAPSHOT-versions:
...
[main] WARNING org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - The POM for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.28-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[main] WARNING org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - The POM for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.29-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[main] WARNING org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - The POM for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.30-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[main] WARNING org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - The POM for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.31-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[main] WARNING org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - The POM for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.32-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[main] WARNING org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - The POM for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.33-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[main] WARNING org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - The POM for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.34-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[main] WARNING org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer - The POM for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.35-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
...

until eventually failing with: "Could not resolve dependencies for project ... org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.35-SNAPSHOT".
Why is it chasing the nonexistent SNAPSHOT instead of simply satisfying the dependency with the normal spring-core-5.3.34.jar?
The Build-target in our .gitlab-ci.yml use jf mvn ...:
include:
  - project: 'foo/bar/shared-templates'
    ref: v1.0.60 # Always use the latest release branch and not the main branch.
    file: 'gitlab-ci/java/11/java11-ci-common-core.yml'

variables:
  ...

Build:
  extends:
    - .java_build_core
    - .java_taglist
  script:
    - jf mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -DskipTests=true package -ntp #This command builds the maven project and packages them into a JAR
  stage: build

Because it builds fine with mvn package on my desktop, I think, something is different in the Gitlab-runner's Maven settings. But what is it -- and is it possible for me to turn it off through either the mvn command-line options, environment variables, or some pom.xml? (I already tried adding -nsu, for example -- to no effect...)

First why you even use version ranges? Second why not using the spring bom instead of manual defining version for spring-core or alike... ? ifyou see the SNAPSHOT versions it looks like you have configured in your repository manager the spring repositories which could contain SNAPSHOT versions... ?

What's "spring bom" and how would I use it?
